# Configure Virtual Agent ServiceNow Embedded automatic login with Api Oauth 2.0

Tags: javascript, php, curl, chatbot, servicenow

i have a website want to add virtual agent / VA (chatbot) in my website.
But my VA always show Guest not logged, besides my API Oauth 2.0 already success and give response (access_token,refresh_token,scope,token_type,expires_in)

I have already configure virtual agent embedded : https://community.servicenow.com/community?id=community_article&sys_id=05289784db7d3cd0ddb1d9d9689619ed

and i create website example : **iframe_va.php**

```
<iframe  id="sn_va_web_client" title="ServiceNow Virtual Agent Client" style="position:fixed; top:0; left:0; bottom:0; right:0; width:100%; height:100%; border:none; margin:0; padding:0; overflow:hidden; z-index:999999;">
</iframe>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.2.4.min.js"></script>
<script>
    $.ajax({
        url: "iframe_va_proses.php",
        type: 'POST',
        data : {username:"admin",pwd:"123"},
        dataType: 'json',
        success: function(res) {
            if(res.access_token){
                document.getElementById('sn_va_web_client').src = "https://you-instance.service-now.com/sn_va_web_client_app_embed.do";
            }
        }
    });
</script>
```

and **iframe_va_proses.php**

```
<?php 
$username     = $_POST['username'];
$password     = $_POST['pwd'];

$curl = curl_init();

curl_setopt_array($curl, array(
  CURLOPT_URL => 'https://you-instance.service-now.com/oauth_token.do',
  CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,
  CURLOPT_ENCODING => '',
  CURLOPT_MAXREDIRS => 10,
  CURLOPT_TIMEOUT => 0,
  CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION => true,
  CURLOPT_HTTP_VERSION => CURL_HTTP_VERSION_1_1,
  CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST => 'POST',
  CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS => 'grant_type=password&client_id=10edd7e527dd8150078b91059065683d&client_secret=.%5E91%3FHd3LO&username='.$username.'&password='.$password,
  CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER => array(
    'Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
    'Cookie: BIGipServerpool_ptberkahjayasentosademo2=2726407690.47166.0000; JSESSIONID=E86B9F8D3DD424CDFDEA7B2DB54372A4; glide_user_activity=U0N2MzoxTTBuYTJVY3Bzbk5hdzgvY0k1Ym9nRzYwZ2VvVFZFazpMTEpXN1RaQ2lJNkltWmI3c09jbzFKY25LenNabmxCbHhsL2RLVHZGc0c4PQ==; glide_user_route=glide.b84c764131cebf3f7460d50c838a7284'
  ),
));

$response = curl_exec($curl);

curl_close($curl);
echo $response;
?>
```

Chatbot still guest account, Chatbot not automatic login
[image]

But, If i'm login in my instance ServiceNow : https://you-instance.service-now.com
and open page **iframe_va.php** chatbot automatic refresh and logged.
[image]
[image]

I want if i'm access iframe_va.php, and return ajax success. VA automatic login, not guest again. I want chatbot login with API Oauth 2.0

Please help me, i'm already searching on google or ServiceNow documentation but no result still guest account :(

Comment: i also have the somewhat same issue. Found any solutions yet?